# Manipulation all model-attributes before the view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Before issuing the "Content" model, I want to search and replace all attributes for placeholders.

I use "tylercd100/laravel-placeholders" to search the placeholders and that works too!

```
public function processVariables()
    {
        Placeholders::setThorough(false);

        $content = \Route::current()->parameter('id');
        $arrContent = Content::findOrFail($content->id);

        $arrPlaceholders = PlaceholdersTraits::setPlaceholders($arrContent);        
        $variables = Placeholders::parse($arrContent, $arrPlaceholders);

        return $variables;
    }
```

Unfortunately it does not work for the output and I can not get any further.

here the error message in the ausag:

> Trying to get property of non-object

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxVh3.png)

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: I have added the error message

Answer (score 0):

\Route::current()->parameter('id') returns string or int, i believe.

Answer (score 0):

With "Placeholders::parse($arrContent, $arrPlaceholders)" i get a string!

How do I convert the string to the Content-Instance (Content::findOrFail($content->id))?